# tshark capture device, specify as UUID

Tags: tshark

When specifying the device for capture, is it possible to give its UUID?

I'm able to give it name, like:

```
tshark -i Ethernet
```

, but not a UUID

Any pointers?;)

Comment: Do you mean the interface index? If you mean the PCI ID, then keep in mind there's no 1:1 mapping between PCI devices and Linux interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

`tshark` doesn't seem to support this out-of-the-box.

On Linux, you can do something like the following:

```
IFINDEX=2
tshark -i $(ip -j a | jq -r ".[] | select(.ifindex==$IFINDEX).ifname")
```